# CSS3 Tooltip: Dependent on width of Parent

Tags: html, css, sass, tooltip

I have a tooltip to show my search when hovering over an icon. That works fine in itself.
My problem is, that this icon is inside an `inline-block` navigation and cause it acts as the parent of my tooltip it has to have the large `width` of it which messes up my layout.
So if I don't extend the width of my parent with the Icon the Tooltip messes up due to the small `width` of `~30px` of it's parent.

[image]

If I extend the width from my parent to 300px (The size of my tooltip), it messes up my layout.

[image]

I need a way of relieving the tooltip itself from the inside of the element with the Icon.

HTML Structure:

```
<div id="search">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="popper inline">
            <i class="fa fa-tags" />
            <div class="tooltip">
                <form>
                    <input placeholder="Search Tags" autocomplete="off" />
                    <button type="submit">
                        <a class="btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-search" />
                        </a>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <div class="inline">
            <form>
                <input placeholder="Search Tags" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" />
                <button type="submit">
                    <a class="btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" />
                    </a>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (Scss):

```
#search {
    background: $secondary;
    padding: .25rem;
    div.popper {
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        font-size: .8rem;
        color: $highlight;
    }
    .inline form {
        button, input, a {
            background: transparent;
            border: none;
            font-size: .8rem;
            color: $highlight;
        }
        input[type="Search"] {
            width: 1368px;
            outline: none;
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: .7rem;
            padding: 1rem .5rem;
        }
        button {
            margin-left: 1rem;
        }
    }
}
.popper {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
.popper .tooltip {
  background: $secondary;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: $highlight;
  display: block;
  left: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: .8rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 90%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
       -o-transform: translateY(10px);
          transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
          transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.popper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.popper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 7px;
  border-right: solid transparent 7px;
  border-top: solid $secondary 7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.popper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

I am grateful for all Your help! If you need further information, comment please.

Comment: Inline elements in HAML always cause a mess, if you encounter things like this I suggest you better use plain HTML for this part as you can skip and type plain HTML in HAML code as well. I never add HAML to inline contents

Comment: Why should I not use Haml in inline elements if they are static. The issue would be exactly the same, if I'd use plain HTML...

Comment: Because I had similar issues and it was fixed this way. http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/ If your problem is different, then better provide us plain html so we can test/fix online like codepen/jsfidle etc

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere. I changed the haml to html.